# Есть ли каталог библиотек C?

Tags: c, библиотеки

Всем привет!

Я сейчас стал применять знания по СИ, активно пишу программу и у меня есть небольшая неясность, которую вы, надеюсь, поможете мне преодолеть. При написании консольного приложения я понял, что стандартных библиотек мне из Кернигана и Ритчи, ну никак не хватает. Я стал разбираться, что мне нужно и выяснил, что мне для написания требуется очень много сторонних библиотек, типа:

```
libcurl (CURl) http://curl.haxx.se/
regex.h
```

Но это очень маленькая часть того, что мне нужно. Но меня в C убило и разозлило, что нет единого официального каталога с документацией по библиотекам( кроме http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/). Это очень сильно напомнило мне язык Javascript - он ущербный и мало функциональный, но когда полностью осваиваешь стороннюю  библиотеку (я освоил фреймворк jQuery + jQuery UI), то просто обалдел от его возможностей.

Подскажите, есть ли подобное в языке C или там всегда был, и есть хаос с библиотеками и документацией к ней?

Спасибо!

Comment: Круто! Истерики много, а содержательной информации мало. Что надо-то? Библиотека на все случаи жизни, чтобы покрывала все потенциальные потребности?

И почему нужны именно http://curl.haxx.se и regex.h? Есть например хорошая библиотека gmp. Вполне можно использовать в консольных приложениях.

Comment: > (я освоил фреймворк jQuery + jQuery UI), то просто обалдел от его возможностей

ИМХО, очень ограниченных, но это уж на вкус и цвет.

Comment: @ВладиславМСК, вы путаете язык и систему программирования. В самом C (именно Си), как языке, нет даже ввода-вывода (как Вы могли бы заметить, внимательно читая книжку K&R).

Comment: В языке Си от K&R -- может быть. В стандарте ISO на язык си -- есть.

Comment: Подскажите, где можно поглядеть этот ISO стандарт? 
Может он мне даст ответ на мой вопрос.....

Comment: Официально -- за деньги на www.iso.org. Нахаляву -- поисковики в помощь. Я видел ISO/IEC 9899:1999 Information technology -- Programming languages -- C. Самый свежий (в гнезде) ISO/IEC 9899:2011 Но это более полутысячи страниц не шибко увлекательного чтения. И на Ваш вопрос там ответ вряд ли найдётся. Гугл дал интересную ссылку http://www.iso-9899.info/wiki/The_Standard Там, например есть ссылка на статью OOP Is Much Better in Theory Than in Practice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, *"там всегда был, и есть хаос с библиотеками и документацией к ней"*. В том смысле, что если вам нужно решить какую-то задачу (например, "прочитать xml-файл", "отправить http-запрос", или "разделить программу на несколько потоков с удобным взаимодействием между ними") то прийдется гуглить нужные решения. Хотя, возможно, есть сайты, где эта информация более-менее систематизирована.

А все потому, что C -- очень старый ЯП. Когда он появился, еще не было моды связывать разработчиков, создавая экосистемы, платформы и прочее.

Comment: Да и пользовательская база слишком велика, чтобы пытаться её увязать  в какой-то единый каталог. Уж слишком много где работают программы на Си.

Comment: Я просто бещусь от геморойности подключения разных библиотек в MS VC 2010. Поэтому каталог с интрукцией по повдключению библиотеки бил бы крут!

Comment: @ВладиславМСК, так Вам все это еще и для Винды требуется ? Вы тогда меточку windows к своему вопросу добавьте.

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/users/232/avp, да для винды. Но если можно, скажите как писать кроссплатформенное консольное приложение на си.

Comment: Что значит "кроссплатформенное консольное приложение на си"? Вот например приложение, не требующее не входящих в поставку библиотек:

    #include <stdio.h>
    int main() {
         printf("Hello, World!\n");
         return 0;
    }

Comment: alexlz, так это понятно. Но вот допустим как использовать кросплатформенно libcurl?
ИЛи есть ещё какая-то библиотека для http запросов и работы с сетью?

Comment: Не понял. Что, для разных платформ интерфейс у libcurl разный? Не верю ((c) Станиславский).

А насчёт "ещё" -- я не гугл. Наверняка есть и далеко не одна (хотя можно и без них обойтись, запрограммировав нужную логику. Вряд ли нужно что-то сложное.

Comment: alexlz, но ведь в разных ОС он по разному подключается(лежит в разных местах). Быть может, я ошибаюсь - поправте тогда.

Comment: Не понял, что значит "в разных местах". В чём проблема? В конце-то концов, если собираете Вы, библиотека находится на Вашем компьютере,  если я -- на моём, т.е. заведомо в разных местах. Или вы спрашиваете, как указать транслятору/линковщику местонахождение библиотеки? Так для разных инструментов -- по-разному. Конкретней, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 4):

Говорят, что для с/с++ есть такой каталог и даже целая система управления всем этим. И называется она Unix(Линукс, FreeBSD и подобные:). Здесь в большинстве случаев заголовочные файлы в одном месте, документация - в другом и так далее. Нужна справка -  запустил man имя_функции и получил.

Comment: И где в Unix (Линукс, FreeBSD и подобные) библиотеки Windows (про исходники и говорить нечего)? Ответ ограниченно верный. Весьма ограниченно.

Comment: никто не сказал, что там есть абсолютно все библиотеки.
С другой стороны, а зачем они там.
С третьей - есть понятие кросскомпиляции, для любителей.
С четвертой - если сильно нужно, то кто мешает их себе добавить?

Comment: А исходники Windows в линуксе - это сильно!

Comment: @KoVadim Ну дык. На глупые вопросы мы даём ещё более глупые ответы. А вопрос не шибко умный.

Comment: @alexz, вообще меня этот вопрос в свое время совсем отвернул от c/c++, а следом и линуха. Не привык малость к такому жестокому и беспросветному бардаку)

Так что глупыми считаю причины возникновения вопроса, а сам он вполне закономерен (особенно, если тс до этого работал с чем-то более программер-френдли).

Comment: @Sh4dow Пошла философия, и какая-то странная. Хотелось бы знать, какой инструмент можно отнести к "программер-френдли".

Comment: @alexlz, та хоть тот же паскаль/делфи, туда же ява, туда же мелкомягкие с бейсиками-сишарпами. По крайней мере можно добавить 3-10 сайтов в закладки и этим обходиться большую часть времени. 

Да, я знаю, что понятный окошечно-кнопочный интерфейс, база библиотек и внятные русскоязычные мануалы развращают программиста, но это не оправдание.

Comment: Хорошо хоть не "интуитивно понятный". бейсик и сишарп языки слишком разной сексуальной ориентации. Борланд паскаль/дельфи -- страшная эклектика (смесь), от которой лучше держаться подальше. Из серии "без штанов, но в галстуке". Мне нравились хелпы для delphi6, где примеры приводились на C. Удобно взять пример, оттранслировать и посмотреть, как работает, "френдли"... А если C/C++ несколько ограничить... Смотрите MS Visual Studio. Там вроде линуховых заморочек нет, все совместимо.

Comment: > А исходники Windows в линуксе

`apt get wine-src`?

Answer (score 3):

Мой вам совет учитесь гуглить на анлийском. В си очень много библиотек на все случаи жизни. Но 99% инфы по ним на английском.

Вот что сходу выдаёт гугл запрос.
A list of open source C libraries
https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/links/libs

Для написания десктопа(и винды и линукса) с GUI есть GTK library.
Чтобы не писать GUI от руки используйте Glade - A User Interface Designer.

Вот вам еще на русском.
13 библиотек С++, о которых нужно знать
https://progtips.ru/biblioteki/13-bibliotek-s-o-kotoryx-nuzhno-znat.html
там часть библиотек написана на си и подходит как раз для него.

Answer (score 0):

[Стандартный набор библиотек GNU C Library с описанием](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/)

ps: На английском языке

Comment: Автор все-таки просит список сторонних библиотек, а вы скидываете единственную библиотеку.