# Существует ли аналог pip для Си?

Tags: c

У [python](/questions/tagged/python) есть [pip](/questions/tagged/pip) для установки сторонних библиотек.
Есть ли подобное для Си ? И если *нет*, то почему ?

Comment: Похожий вопрос 
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/111600/Есть-ли-каталог-библиотек-c

Comment: Си - это язык. Пакет не может касаться языка. Например VS - студия - это среда. И у VS есть и "пакеты" и управление пакетами. Кстати для питона - пакеты могут быть только как для среды, а не как для языка.

Comment: а у си есть apt get/yum/emerge или что там поддерживается в Вашей операционке

Comment: @nick_n_a [может](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTibh.jpg).

Comment: К частью, в Си нет никаких пакетов! Здесь полная свобода, и можно использовать любую DLL, и многое другое. Пакеты создаются в виду ограничений каких то сред. На Си же пишутся и расширения к другим языкам, в основном.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Си - это язык для написания программ, и в спецификацию языка не входит управление пакетами. Можно разве что проверить "подключен пакет" или нет при определенных условиях. Питон - можно рассматривать как язык, в спецификации языка может быть только "проверка наличия" пакета. А управлять пакетами, используя язык - нельзя.

Пакеты могут быть исключительно у *среды разработки*.

У среды разработки Питон - управление пакетами есть.

Для С++ управление пакетами есть в:

1. `Dev C++`
2. `Borland C++ Builder` (такие же как в Delphi). Одно время были популярны сайты распространяющие библиотеки для Delphi и Borland C++ в составе пакетов.
3. `Eclipse IDE` позволяет так же работать с С++, и доставлять пакеты библиотек.

Answer (score 0):

У Си нет такого подхода, потому что у Си это иначе.

Библиотеки - то просто `.DLL` файлы (плюс `.h` файлы плюс документация для программистов), которые присоединяются к (уже скомпилированной) программе в фазе соединения.

Comment: А что вы скажете, например про NuGet?

Comment: Что вы скажете, про систему контроля версий библиотек в Windows?

Comment: Причём тут *.DLL*? нет в си никаких .DLL

Comment: @nick_n_a - NuGet нет менеджером пакетов для *Си*, а для среды *.NET*.

Comment: @nick_n_a - Система контроля версий - это совсем другое.

Comment: По-моему в DevC есть пакеты. И в borland есть пакеты, может не сильно развитые, но есть.

Comment: @alexolut, вы совсем правилен. Мой ответ только с практической точки зрения.

Comment: @nick_n_a - Может быть, но вы говорите только об двух разных IDE - это опять только *среды* для программистов, не сам язык программирования .