# Почему библиотеку C не обновляют?

Tags: c++, c, библиотеки, стандарт

Например, почти в каждом проекте нужен вектор. Почему его до сих пор не добавили? С++ обновляют каждые 3 года.

Comment: потому что C - это для другого, там вектора особенно не нужны :) когда низкоуровневые драйвера кодите, да и C занял свою нишу уже, не надо его в совсем уже универсальное средство превращать, а то еще и Фортран оживлять решите :)))

Comment: malloc/realloc + указатель - вот и вектор.

Comment: @KoVadim так почему не добавили за пару десятков лет?

Comment: так оно уже есть, изначально.

Comment: @KoVadim функции/структуры для работы с вектором? Только сторонние библиотеки

Comment: Одной из целей комитета C89 при написании самого первого [международного] стандарта языка C была «*сохранить дух языка*», в том числе *сохранять язык маленьким и простым* (это из “The Rationale for ISO — Programming Languages — C”). Вот и ответ. Стандартная библиотека с миллионами разных возможностей противоречит самому духу языка. Если вам нужно разнообразие — добро пожаловать в ад C++.

Comment: @eanmos так расширение стандартной библиотеки не влияет на "размер языка", т.е. новых ключевых слов не появляется. Никто не просит миллионов возможностей, просто подключать каждый раз несколько сторонних библиотек для структур данных вместо одной стандартной надоедает

Comment: не нужно ничего стороннего подключать. malloc/realloc - часть стандарта. VLA - никто не отменял.

Comment: чтобы умел int'ы хранить? )

Comment: Может чтобы не слишком снижать порог вхождения? (шутка). А если серьезней, то [вот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/899071/232)

Comment: @Япок Акал, как это не влияет? Стандартная библиотека -- часть стандарта. Ну вот вам нужен вектор, кому-то еще -- хэш-таблица, еще кому-то -- динамическая строка понадобится...